# where is the implementation of smbc_open() function in libsmbclient

Tags: samba, libsmbclient

I am taking a look at the implementation of `libsmbclient`. The source code I have for samba is 4.1.13. I can find the example `testXXX.c` functions which shows the examples of using `libsmbclient functions`. I also found a header file called `libsmbclient.h` which has all these function prototypes definitions, such as `smbc_open`, `smbc_read` and so on. I want to see the really implementation of `smbc_open()` function, and some other functions. I did `grep -r 'smbc_open' *`, but I didn't find any place that has the implementation of this function. All I see are the callers calling this function or this prototype definition. So where can I find this function implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. All these smbc_open(), close() ... functions are implemented in libsmb_compat.c